How to link 3 SQL tables and pass 0 value if the value is NULL
I am trying to create a query for my website to get the total number of active users for a selected time period and for a specific user account ID to filter for teams.
My current query works but without a specific user account ID so this is for the total users and for my weekly time period (active users the past week including today):
WITH RECURSIVE Dates AS (
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY AS date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    FROM Dates
    WHERE date < CURDATE()
) 
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN "weekly" = "biannually" THEN DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(Dates.date) - 1) DAY) 
        WHEN "weekly" = "yearly" THEN DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(Dates.date) - 1) DAY) 
        WHEN "weekly" = "daily" THEN DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") 
    ELSE 
        date
    END AS id, 
COALESCE(COUNT(activity_user), 0) AS users
FROM Dates 
    LEFT JOIN activity ON date = activity_date
    LEFT JOIN users ON activity_user = users_id
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC;

This is the result:
+------------+-------+
| id         | users |
+------------+-------+
| 2024-10-02 |     25|
| 2024-10-03 |     64|
| 2024-10-04 |     10|
| 2024-10-05 |     22|
| 2024-10-06 |     27|
| 2024-10-07 |     16|
| 2024-10-08 |      3|
+------------+-------+

The issue is that if I try to do:
LEFT JOIN users ON activity_user = users_id WHERE users_account = 10 for my second left join, to filter for the account with ID of 10, I get an empty set instead of showing me the dates but with 0 users, for each date. The expected result should be:
+------------+-------+
| id         | users |
+------------+-------+
| 2024-10-02 |      0|
| 2024-10-03 |      0|
| 2024-10-04 |      0|
| 2024-10-05 |      0|
| 2024-10-06 |      0|
| 2024-10-07 |      0|
| 2024-10-08 |      0|
+------------+-------+

And if I do:
LEFT JOIN users ON activity_user = users_id AND users_account = 10, it gets disregarded completely and doesn't work and I get my original result of:
+------------+-------+
| id         | users |
+------------+-------+
| 2024-10-02 |     25|
| 2024-10-03 |     64|
| 2024-10-04 |     10|
| 2024-10-05 |     22|
| 2024-10-06 |     27|
| 2024-10-07 |     16|
| 2024-10-08 |      3|
+------------+-------+

I have tried using every type of SQL JOIN for these tables but none of them seem to work. I simply want to filter by the user_account field and to show 0 on dates that have no active users. It works for the total amount of users but not when I want to filter for a specific team (user_account).

This looks a bit weird: "weekly" = "biannually". We use double quotes for names in SQL. So there are two columns, "weekly" and "biannually" the content of wich you compare? Or are these supposed to be strings? In that case we'd use single quotes. But 'weekly' = 'biannually'will always be false of course, as the strings differ. Or is there a column weekly that you want to compare with a string 'biannually'? Then do exactly that:weekly = 'biannually'`.

COALESCE is superfluous in your query by the way. A COUNT result can never be NULL, it will always be 0 or a positive integer.

You should not name a CTE the same as the underlying table (Dates). This is confusing.

As to the data model: Don't give your columns names starting with the table name. This can lead to queries that are less eadable because of the long names. You can always qualify columns with the table name instead, which you should. Like calling the activity date just date and then LEFT JOIN activity ON activity.date = dates.date. Or with using alias names, which can often get a query even more readable: FROM dates d LEFT JOIN activity a ON a.date = d.date.

The below code is for where you got an empty result but expected all zeros. I think that meant user_account 10 did not log on those days.
Can you try,
WITH RECURSIVE Dates AS (SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY AS date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    FROM Dates
    WHERE date < CURDATE()) 
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN "weekly" = "biannually" THEN DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(Dates.date) - 1) DAY) 
        WHEN "weekly" = "yearly" THEN DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(Dates.date) - 1) DAY) 
        WHEN "weekly" = "daily" THEN DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") 
    ELSE 
        date
    END AS id, 
if(users_account is null, "0", COALESCE(COUNT(activity_user), 0) ) AS users
FROM Dates 
    LEFT JOIN activity ON date = activity_date
    left JOIN users ON activity_user = users_id
where users_account = 10
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC;


You outer join activities and users so as to get dates without activities. In an outer joined row, the user columns are null.
With
WHERE users_account = 10

you dismiss all rows that have another user, but also all outer joined rows, because their user_account is null, thus dismissing any date from your result that doesn't have a user-10 activity.
With
ON ... AND users_account = 10

you properly outer join the users you are interested in, but then you COUNT(activity_user). This counts you all activities, no matter what user, as for other users you still joined the activity, but got empty user columns. So instead count the rows that have a user-10 match:
COUNT(users_id)

